# Finding dgettext declaration when compiling libmypaint on osx

Tags: macos, gimp

I have been trying to compile GIMP for the last few days from source and I am having an issue with libmypaint.

I have read the REAMDME, and install all dependencies via MacPort. The autogen.sh file completes, but when I run the ./configure, I get the

> following line of code:

```
checking for libintl.h... yes
checking for ngettext in libc... no
checking for bindtextdomain in -lintl... no
checking if -liconv is needed to use gettext... 
checking for ngettext in -lintl... no
checking for library containing dgettext... no
configure: error: no dgettext
```

I am on `OSX`, and have installed the following packages via `macports`:

```
sudo port install gtk2 gegl-0.3 babl atk fontconfig freetype harfbuzz gdk-pixbuf2 glib2 bzip2 libpng xz zlib aalib ghostscript jasper libmng librsvg xpm openexr swig scons json-c py27-numpy py27-scipy py27-pyobjc py27-py2app py27-macholib py27-modulegraph py27-altgraph py27-pyobjc-cocoa lcms2 py27-gobject3 hicolor-icon-theme php71 mhash php_select php71-gettext gobject-introspection intltool automake autoconf libcxx
```

Any help will be appreciated

Regards

Comment: Maybe file this as a bug against Macports?

Comment: Hi, If I download gettext from source and install, the libmypaint compile. I have started again with a clean macport install. Will report to macport once I establish what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The reason i wanted to install libmypaint was to compile gimp from source code. to install gimp is difficult as it require a lot of packages. It also did not recognize installs in `/opt/local`. This forced me to install the packages manually and they all resided in `usr/local`. Duplication was the order and this caused issues with compiling libmypaint.

It seems I resolved issue, after several tries. I am currently on OSX 10.12, with Xcode 7.3.1. I had installed a lot of MacPort packages, Brew packages and other random source code, thus my `/opt/local` and `/user/local` and `brew` folder was cluttered. PKG-Config was not installed or not visible, also causing a few issues.

I decided to do the following:

1. Remove content in  `opt/local`, `/usr/local` and remove all brew and MacPort packages.
2. Deleted all off MacPort and Brew
3. I decided that my preferred packages manager is MacPort(just because I know it better. Brew is good, but I will not advise in installing packages manually. It takes time :))
4. Installed just the bare minimum packages for libmypaint to compile using port:

> sudo port selfupdate
>
> sudo port install expat libiconv ncurses gettext
>
> sudo port install autoconf  automake cmake libtool zlib pcre libffi glib2 curl curl-ca-bundle libarchive  libxml2  xz  lzo2 intltool pkgconfig
>
> sudo port install json-c

I got libmypaint to compile.

Comment: Is /opt/local supposed to be a standard location for development files? You might be expected to set up environment variables - if macports puts stuff there,  it might provide a script to do that for you.